# Akka: Forward message from one actor to another

Tags: akka

Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

I am a newbie to AKKA and trying to expand the akka-java-spring sample code to add another actor and have a immutable object Counter used as a message to be sent to CoutingActor which prints a message and the forwards it to a PrintMessageActor (new actor). How do I forward the message to PrintMessageActor  from CoutingActor. How do I use the below snippet from the documentation to use in this case.

```
target.forward(result, getContext());
```

how to get the target (2nd actor) in the first actor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to know from where the forwarding actor knows the target it should forward to?

Two possibilities:

1) If the target actor already exists when the forwarding actor gets incarnated, then you could simply pass it the target's `ActorRef` via the constructor or in a message. See [Props](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html) documentation for how to create custom Props instances with own parameters.

2) If the target does not exist at creation of the forwarder but its path in the `ActorSystem` is already clear (e.g. "/user/PrintMessageActor"), then you can pass in an `ActorSelection`. An ActorSelection can resolve to an ActorRef, if an Actor in this path exists in the given ActorSystem. Preferable is this second option since an ActorRef will be invalid if the underlying actor dies. An ActorSelection on the other hand will resolve to an possible new incarnation of the Actor at this path.

Comment: Thank You Bjorn. I will try to use the second option. I also wanted to create child actors for CoutingActor and PrintMessageActor. How are child actors created in the parent actor and how can the message be handled by child actors?

What I am trying to do is - pass message to CoutingActor - the children of this actor prints a message and then the message is passed to PrintMessageActor - which has childrens and they print a message. I also want to control the number of childrens the parent actors can have. I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hallo Sachin. You can create as many child actors as you want. The only difference between creating first-level actors and child-actors is the object which does the creation for you. If you want to create an first-level actor (like "/user/MyActor") then you use the ActorSystem directly, say system.actorOf(...) for an ActorRef or system.actorSelection(...) for an ActorSelection. Child-actor can be created from within an Actor using the ActorContext. (context.actorOf / .actorSelection)

Comment: (cont.) Sending all children the same message (a broadcast) can be achieved in two ways. Either you iterate over the "children" property of your parent actor, sending them all the same message - or you use a special type of intermediary actor called a Router. There are several different implementations of this Router, one is the BroadcastRouter which would fit your needs. But in such a simple case, I personally would prefer just iterating over the children.

Comment: I do like the idea of Router. I am working on this piece to learn about Akka to put together a POC for my work. Could you guide me to a link where I can find a example code in Java which I can take a look at? Some working example that has more than one Parent actors and each parent actor having few child actors. Most of the examples I have seen are in Scala and I am not very familiar with it. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Actually, the Akka documentation has an useful example. I didn't check the whole example but browsing the code, I found that child actors are instantiated and also a router is being used. All in Java. Have a look at that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html By the way, If you found my answer useful, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. We're all longing for those points here at SO. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, I just marked it as accepted :). I found this in the documentation - target.forward(result, getContext()); but wasn't sure how to get the reference for target (which is a another actor). The documentation did not mention that.